# Does trigger API in quartz clustered scheduler triggers job in the same local machine or any machine in the cluster?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

When I trigger a job in Quartz in a clustered setup, does that trigger job only on the same machine, or any machine in the clustered setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quartz documentation on [Clustering](http://quartz-scheduler.org/generated/2.2.1/html/qs-all/#page/Quartz_Scheduler_Documentation_Set%2Fco-adv_clustering.html%23) says (emphasis mine):

> Only one node will fire the job for each firing. For example, if the job has a repeating trigger that tells it to fire every 10 seconds, then at 12:00:00 exactly one node will run the job, and at 12:00:10 exactly one node will run the job, etc. **It won't necessarily be the same node each time - it will more or less be random which node runs it**. The load balancing mechanism is near-random for busy schedulers (lots of triggers) but favors the same node that just was just active for non-busy (e.g. one or two triggers) schedulers.

Basically, once a job is scheduled to run, this information is written to the database.  Any node from the cluster can read from this database and run the job.